# String linked list in C

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I am new to linked list in C and the problem I have is that I am trying to make a linked list of Strings, but when I try to print that list it prints first char from two different strings. I think I am messing some pointers. Any help please?
Here is my code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    typedef struct _song{char *songTitle; char *songAuthor; char *songNote; struct _song *next;}SONG;

    int songCount =4;


    char SongTitle[songCount];
    char AuthorName[songCount];
    char SongNotes[songCount];


    char songTitle0[21] = "19 problems";
    char songArtist0[21]="JayZ";
    char songNotes0[81]="JiggaWhoJiggaWhat";
    SongTitle[0]=*songTitle0;//points at string songTitle0
    AuthorName[0]=*songArtist0;
    SongNotes[0]=*songNotes0;

    char songTitle1[21] = "Cig Poppa";
    char songArtist1[21]="Biggie Smalls";
    char songNotes1[81]="I Luv it When you call me big poppa";
    SongTitle[1]=*songTitle1;
    AuthorName[1]=*songArtist1;
    SongNotes[1]=*songNotes1;

    SONG *CurrentSong, *header, *tail;

    int tempCount=0;
    header = NULL;

    for(tempCount=0;tempCount<songCount;tempCount++)
    {

        CurrentSong = malloc(sizeof(struct _song));
        CurrentSong->songTitle= &SongTitle[tempCount];
        CurrentSong->songAuthor=&AuthorName[tempCount];
        CurrentSong->songNote=&SongNotes[tempCount];

        if(header == NULL)
        {
            header=CurrentSong;//head points to first thing in memory
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next=CurrentSong;
        }
        tail = CurrentSong;//always the last thing in the list 
        tail->next=NULL;//the next pointer is null always

    }
    tempCount =0;
    for(CurrentSong=header; CurrentSong!=NULL; CurrentSong=CurrentSong->next)
                    {
                        printf("\n%d: ", tempCount);
                            printf("Title: %s ",CurrentSong->songTitle);


                        printf("Author: %s ",CurrentSong->songAuthor);
                        tempCount++;
                    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how you're supposed to use linked lists.

It's

```
typedef struct list {
    void *data;
    struct list *next;
}
SONG *s = (SONG *)songList->data;
```

Likewise, for cloning strings, you need to use `strdup`.

E.g.

```
s->songTitle = strdup(SongTitle);
s->songAuthor = strdup(AuthorName);
s->songNote = strdup(SongNotes);
```

Don't forget to `free` the strings once you're done with them.

Answer (score 0):

```
SongTitle[0]=*songTitle0;//points at string songTitle0
```

The comment is not true. You're copying the first character `songTitle0` into the first position of `SongTitle`.

Your setup far too complex. You'll want to just assign `songTitle0`, without any `*` or `&`, to the `songTitle` element of the list's first link; both are of type `char*`, so that's just a pointer copy. Skip the `SongTitle`, `AuthorName` and `SongNotes` variables, they serve no purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The three variables SongTitle, AuthorName and SongNotes are array of `char`, not array of `string`. You need to change their declaration to:

```
char* SongTitle[songCount];
char* AuthorName[songCount];
char* SongNotes[songCount];
```

Then, you need to update them like that:

```
SongTitle[0] = songTitle0;//points at string songTitle0
AuthorName[0] = songArtist0;
SongNotes[0] = songNotes0;
```

And when you store them in the linked list:

```
    CurrentSong = malloc(sizeof(struct _song));
    CurrentSong->songTitle = SongTitle[tempCount];
    CurrentSong->songAuthor = AuthorName[tempCount];
    CurrentSong->songNote = SongNotes[tempCount];
```